# How do I Add Azure Functions at Run Time

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a class library with methods that I want to map and execute as Azure Functions.

How those methods should get mapped up (e.g. as timer, http trigger, what http verb or route to use, etc.) for our use case is **not known at design/compile time, but at run time**.

This is at odds with the prescribed way of making a function class and decorating it with Azure Function attributes. We can't declare the attributes, since that information isn't available to us at compile time.

How can I declare/define/bind azure functions against my class library's methods at **run time** (such as when the function app starts)?

I have noticed that if you create new function.json files/folders the runtime will restart the app to pick up the changes. I attempted to just write out a new function.json pointing to the desired code, but when I try to access the endpoint, it fails with the (very true) complaint that my class method is not decorated with attributes. Because I can't, as above.

I would prefer a solution that works with Azure Functions V1 and V2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this scenario is not supported.

Your best option might be to have two Function Apps: one "management" app which decides what needs to be done and which generates the code and bindings for the second app. As you can imagine, that's a slippery and creative road to follow.

Similar advice was given to my similar question [in this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1597).